# Variable expression into javascript without using th:inline

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I searched first but I found confusing answers since I'm new to Thymeleaf and amateurish at best at javascript.

I just want to know how to pass variable expressions into javascript functions, sort of like in JSP:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:getContactId('${contact.id}');">Button</a>
```

Of course, this fails with Thymeleaf and passes the string ${contact.id} instead of its value, so how could I get the value of the variable expression instead?

The reason I want it this way is because it depends on the row which is being iterated by `th:each`.

If there's no other way except to use `th:inline`, then what's the best approach considering the above statement?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This one worked:

```
th:onclick="'javascript:getContactId(\'' + ${contact.id} + '\');'"
```

Thanks goes out to the thymeleaf forum:
http://forum.thymeleaf.org/variable-expression-into-javascript-without-using-th-inline-td4025534.html

Comment: This works for me, with one parameter, but I can't (yet) see how that looks like with two parameters?

Comment: Ah nevermind, got it! For (example) a fixed string param, the above will be `th:onclick="'javascript:getContactId(\'someString\',\'' + ${contact.id} + '\');'"` Cool, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In Thymeleaf version 2.1, I have not been able to get the accepted answer to work. I did find some guidance from a [Twitter post from Thymeleaf](https://twitter.com/thymeleaf/status/95830189258444800). Rather than using `th:onclick`, you use `th:attr` and specify the onclick attribute therein.

```
th:attr="onclick='javascript:getContactId(\'' + ${contact.id} + '\');'"
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! This is the only thing that worked for me. It is a bit annoying that the answer had to be found in a cryptic tweet! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can not put `javascript` variables into `onclick` or other DOM attributes. The value of `onclick` or any other DOM attribute should be a constant string.

However, you can dynamically modify value of onclick attribute from javascript, like this:

```
yourDomElement.onclick = anyVariable;
```

Comment: what do you mean? this would be part of an <a> tag.

Comment: the part of <a> tag should be a constant string. Dynamically you can do that from inside <script language="javascript"> block

Comment: do you mean that I should not? Because this has worked for me in the past.

Comment: I'm calling an external function by its name, the whole function isn't there. Anyway this isn't part of my problem..

Comment: once agagin, value passed to onclick inside <a> element should be a constant string. You can not pass javascript variables there. To do so you should set value of yourDomElement.onclick from javascript.

Comment: Well with all due respect, I can, and it's obviously working because it is debugging as passing ${contact.id} to the controller - not to mention it has worked before. That's why I asked if you meant that I should not do it that way as per proper practice, or something.

Comment: it's passing constant string which you specified.

Comment: Ok I understand what you're saying now, and you are correct in every way. But I have a view resolver (thymeleaf) which changes my `${contact.id}` into whatever the java class behind it has so as far as js/DOM goes it still static on page load. Though you did give me an idea of what to try next...

Comment: I'm new to thymeleaf so I can't help you with it. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like:

th:onclick="'javascript:getContactId(\'' + ${contact.id} + '\');'"

Answer (score 0):

A more generic approach, if you need in JS something that isn't passed as a event handler parameter:

`th:attr="data-myValueFromThymeleaf=${contact.id}"`

Any attribute whose name is starting with data- is ignored by all browsers. So it won't affect the UI and you can easily read the value in javascript.

I prefer this because it's not ideal to put javascript code in html ([see unobtrusive javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript))

Answer (score 0):

I have asked the Thymeleaf project on twitter, and their answer is:

You can use both the "+" operator or literal substitutions. For example: `<a th:href="|javascript:change('start','${taskId}')|">`

For more info: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standarddialect5minutes.html

I have tried, and it works~