# Thymeleaf: &#39; added on passing parameter to javascript function

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

Below code in thymeleaf template view is calling javascript function filter:

```
<select th:onchange="'filter(this, \'' + ${#lists.size(books)} + '\');'">
    <option value="all" selected="selected">All Books</option>
    <option value="fav">My Favourite</option>
</select>
```

But, ${#lists.size(books)} is prefixed and suffixed with `&#39;` as shown in the view-source:

```
<select onchange="filter(this, &#39;1&#39;);">
    <option value="all" selected="selected">All Books</option>
    <option value="fav">My Favourite</option>
</select>
```

How to remove `&#39;` from javascript function call in Thymeleaf?

Comment: Before checking anything else, you have `\''` and then `'\'`. That is definitely not right. Do you mean `'\'` in both?

Comment: this is how we pass thymeleaf parameters to javascript. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365746/variable-expression-into-javascript-without-using-thinline?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&#39;` is how you escape the apostrophe in tag attributes in an HTML4-compatible way. Your code is OK, and it should work perfectly.