# how to get thymeleaf value in script?

Tags: javascript, ajax, thymeleaf

Could not parse as expression: `"'getCandidateId('\' + ${candidate.id} + '\');'"`

**code:**

```
<a href="#" th:onclick="'getCandidateId('\' + ${candidate.id} + '\');'"></a>
```

**in JS:**

```
getCandidateId(cid){
    alert(cid);

}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365746/variable-expression-into-javascript-without-using-thinline if this would help...

Comment: Add code tags. It will improve readability.