# Thymeleaf: combining literals with variables

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this piece of code in Thymeleaf:

```
<tr th:each="image: ${images}" >
    <img th:onmouseover="'javascript:imageName(\'theImageName\' + ${image.id} +'\');'"> 
</tr>
```

but I got a parsing error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two observations:

**Open Tag?**

Some Thymeleaf template modes require that the template be well-formed. If this is the case, any *unclosed* `img` tag will result in a parsing error.

When this happens, the java stack trace is informative:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "img" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</img>".
```

but the error you may see in the browser isn't:

```
Exception parsing document: template="home", line 19 - column 6
```

My minimally configured Spring Boot app defaults to one of these stricter modes (`HTML5`? `XML`?), so both @Metroids' and @ErikMD's answers give me a parsing error as they are, but both work if I close the image tags.

If this isn't the case for you, updating the question with the java stack trace might help.

**Pipes**

I think all these apostrophes and plus signs make the markup difficult to read (and write).  Using [literal substitutions with pipes](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions) is arguably more legible (and less error-prone):

```
<img th:onmouseover="|javascript:imageName('ImageName${image.id}');|" />
```

or even:

```
<img th:onmouseover="|imageName('ImageName${image.id}')|" />
```

If you don't like this approach, the code in your question can also be fixed by removing the backslash after `theImageName`:

```
<img th:onmouseover="'javascript:imageName(\'theImageName' + ${image.id} +'\');'" />
```

Answer (score 1):

can you try the following

```
<img th:onmouseover="'javascript:imageName(\''+ theImageName\' + ${image.id} +'\');'">
```

Comment: @enLopes Could you please try now? I have updated my answer

Comment: same result :-(

Answer (score 1):

I'd format it like this:

```
<tr th:each="image: ${images}" >
    <img th:onmouseover="${'javascript:imageName(''theImageName' + image.id + ''');'}"> 
</tr>
```

Comment: @enLopes I tested this with variables... if you're still getting parsing errors, something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following code instead?

```
<img th:attr="onmouseover=${'javascript:imageName(''theImageName' + image.id + ''');'}">
```

This answer was inspired by [that other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25496747/9164010) and the relevant section of the Thymeleaf documentation is [5.1: Setting the value of any attribute](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-the-value-of-any-attribute).